# How to find sorted previous element in jquery .?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="con" >
    <p class="bb">1</p>
    <p class="aa">2</p>
    <p class="aa">3</p>
    <p class="bb">4</p> /*----- i want this reference */
    <p class="aa">5</p>
    <p class="aa">6</p>
    <p id="last" class="aa">7</p>
    <p class="aa">6</p>
    <p class="aa">6</p>
</div>
```

i want to find the previous element among the siblings with sorted value.
here i want to find the 'p' has class 'aa' previous to #last

```
$("#last").prev('p.bb').text()
```

// empty string

```
 $("#last").prev().text()
```

//will give **6**

i want 4.. just the text of previous closest 'p.bb'

Comment: you are expecting the result 6 .. right ?

Comment: Looking at his first selector it seems he wants '4'; but I'm honestly not sure. Sarath: could you please clarify what result you want?

Comment: i want 4.. just the text of previous closest 'p.aa'

Comment: To get '4' you're looking at the text of the previous closest `p.bb`, the previous closest `p.aa` is '6'. If you take a look at my answer, does that return what you want? Or am I still missing something?

Comment: yess sory for the typeerror its p.bb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure of what, precisely, you're looking for, but assuming you want to find the last `p` of class `bb` that comes before your `#last` element:

```
var $last = $('#last');

var lastIndex = $last.index('#con p');

for (i=lastIndex; i>=0; i--){
    if ($('#con p').eq(i).hasClass('bb')){
        $('#con p').eq(i).css('background-color','#f00');
        alert($('#con p').eq(i).text());
        break;
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sWMEF/1/).

While this is rather more verbose than [@voigtan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581977/how-to-find-sorted-previous-element-in-jquery/7582055#7582055)'s answer it allows you to use *any* arbitrary element, and ensures that the `.bb` element found always occurs prior to that element.

Comment: $("#last").prevAll("p.bb:first") should do the same.

Answer (score 2):

is it:

```
$("#last").siblings('p.bb:last').text()
```

that you are looking for? demo: http://jsbin.com/opaqen/edit

or is it like:

http://jsbin.com/opaqen/2/edit

or use `.prevAll()` to get all previous siblings from #last:

```
var lastB = $("#last").prevAll("p.bb:first");
lastB.css("background-color","#f00");
```

Comment: closest to what? a sibling that not has the same class as the last? Then you may want to use: http://jsbin.com/opaqen/2/edit

Comment: closest sibling to $("#last"),

Comment: Then I dont really understand your question. `$("#last").prev()` is the closest sibling witch is: `<p class="aa">6</p>`. and not `<p class="bb">4</p>`